# Uploading a file using codeception in a explorer window

Tags: windows, selenium, file-upload, codeception, explorer

I have to test an file import in our browser software.
The issue is that when i click the import button it opens a windows explorer window and i can't select the file from that window.
I am using codeception with selenium 2.53 and firefox 47.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Codeception's webdriver module provides a method for attaching a file to an html form:

```
$I->attachFile('input[@type="file"]', 'prices.xls');
```

You only need to be able to target the button or the form, and specify the path to the file you want to upload